# How to add image using GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a problem I would like to display images using GridView, but it is not working. Images are upluded already

Here is a code

```
<asp:Gridview id="zbozi" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="zbozi_RowCommand1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="zbozi_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_pocitace" HeaderText="ID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="nazev" HeaderText="Název" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="cena" HeaderText="Cena" />
        
               HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PUT IMAGES


              <asp:BoundField DataField="popis" HeaderText="Popis" />  

    </Columns>   
</asp:Gridview>
```

This is Cs

```
public partial class online : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["idecko"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

        }
        uziv.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["uziv"]);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["logins"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlDa = new SqlCommand("select * from pocitace", conn);
        var rdr = sqlDa.ExecuteReader();
        zbozi.DataSource = rdr;
        zbozi.DataBind();
```

Image of visual studio, folders etc.. for understanding the situation:

[image: image of visual studio, folders etc.. for understanding the situation]

Answer (score 0):

To show image in GridView, you need to create a column with "ImageField".

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="testGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image"></asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then access the image path in the database directly and bind the data from database like:

```
string constr = @"connection string";
con.Open();
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TestTable", con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
testGridView.DataSource = ds;
testGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

dont upload binary or like this in sql just upload the path and get the path

add this column

<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="image_Path" HeaderText="Image"></asp:ImageField>

and set column name İmage_Path nvarchar in sql

Comment: i have that but problem was eaxactly at the path because there was missing this sign ~

Comment: you must be use nvarchar variable if u dont use not set  this sign ~

Comment: thanks and what is the difference between vchar and nvchar?

Comment: nvarchar is  supported UTF-8  and check this link https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-varchar-data-type-deep-dive/#:~:text=The%20key%20difference%20between%20varchar,the%20space%20as%20SQL%20varchar.